# Dask doesn't group/apply the results properly compared to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I have a very large (150M rows - 30GB RAM) dataframe. I do a groupby (around 40 groups) and apply a function on each group. Takes about 30 minutes to perform everything. Here was the code I used:

```
df = df.groupby(by='date').apply(func=my_func)
```

Since the operations are not interdependant, I figured I'd use Dask to parallelize the processing of each group seperately.

So I use this code:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd



df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df_pandas, npartitions=40)
template = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
df_dask = df_dask.groupby(by='date').apply(func=my_func, meta=template)
df_dask = df_dask.compute()
```

However, when I run this, I get different results depending on the value of **npartitions** I give it. If I give a value of 1, it gives me the same (and correct) results, but then it takes the same amount of time as with pandas. If I give it a higher number, it performs faster, but returns way fewer rows. I don't understand the relationship between npartitions and the groupby.

Also, if I try with a slightly larger DataFrame (40GB), Dask runs out of memory, even though I have 64GB on my machine, while pandas is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue, I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Dask's DataFrameGroupBy.apply applies the user-provided function to each partition: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.

If you need a custom reduction, use Aggregate: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's not happening here. If I understand correctly, the npartitions shouldn't affect the results, right? Because it only depends on the groups. Well in this case, it changes the results, hence my question.